# C Binder Switch in Gnatbind

Tags: gnat

I was looking at newer versions of the GNAT tools and saw that Gnatbind no longer has a switch for generating the C Binder files, "-C".

Is this binder file no longer necessary for mixed language environments or was it's functionality moved to another switch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mixed language projects has nothing to do with it. Binding is an Ada-exclusive. There is no binding in C or C++

AdaCore chose to remove this switch because:

- Ada generated code is sufficient (we removed this switch when it was becoming obsolete, so we switched to Ada binding and never had any issues)
- Keeping the "generate binding in C" would require them to maintain both versions of the binder generation code.
- That allows for pure Ada-compiled programs.

And you still can mix C/C++/Ada sources in your project. Bind only occurs if there are some Ada source files in the project (`"Ada"` must be present in `Languages` section of the .gpr file and at least one Ada source file must be present too)